# Git line number before and after

Tags: git

I have some master commits in my git repo. Some of commits are tagged with git tags.
Let's look at example:

```
commits:  Master -> Master -> Master -> Master
tags:       v1        v2        v3       HEAD
```

Now I have a report that at v2 is an error on file *filename* at line 45.

Is there any way to get line number based on HEAD and line number 45 in v2?

`git diff HEAD v2 filename` show me differences but what I really want is just "new" line number.

To be more specific if I added 3 lines at v3 commit and than remove 1 line in latest (HEAD) commit, some `git` command should result me 45 + 3 - 1 = 47. Is there any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Far easier IMHO would be to use git blame:

```
git blame $ref -L'/search_pattern/,+1' filename(s)
```

A full-on example on my zfs-fuse repository:

```
$ git for-each-ref --format='%(refname)' -- refs/heads |
       while read ref; 
            do git blame $ref -L'/push/,+1' zfs_operations.c; 
       done
```

*As you can see, half the work is in getting the branch names; You can of course simply hardcode revisions if that's easier for your usage.* Output from the above:

```
f5370a5e (Emmanuel Anne 2011-02-22 20:53:17 +0100 1492) static void push(zfsvfs_t *zfsvfs, cred_t *cred, fuse_ino_t ino, file_info_t *info, const char *buf, size_t size, off_t off)
f5370a5e (Emmanuel Anne 2011-02-22 20:53:17 +0100 1512) static void push(zfsvfs_t *zfsvfs, cred_t *cred, fuse_ino_t ino, file_info_t *info, const char *buf, size_t size, off_t off)
f5370a5e (Emmanuel Anne 2011-02-22 20:53:17 +0100 1512) static void push(zfsvfs_t *zfsvfs, cred_t *cred, fuse_ino_t ino, file_info_t *info, const char *buf, size_t size, off_t off)
```

Note the line numbers (**1492** vs. **1512**):

> f5370a5e (Emmanuel Anne 2011-02-22 20:53:17 +0100 **1512**) static void push(zfsvfs_t *zfsvfs, cred_t *cred, fuse_ino_t ino, file_info_t *info, const char *buf, size_t size, off_t off)

Any revisions that do no match the search pattern, will show

```
fatal: -L parameter 'push': No match
```

---

You'll additionally want to look at the options:

```
 -M    (detect moved lines)
 -n    (show source line number)
 -f    (show filename, especially handy with -C)
 -p / --incremental: if you want something parsed more easily in code
```